# Crear condición si el valor de la llave foranea no coincide

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter y dentro de mis tablas también he creado llaves foráneas, una de ellas es que no puedo crear horas medicas si el rut del medico no existe (es para saber a quien le corresponde la hora)

lo cual de existir el rut se inserta sin problemas los datos pero al no existir me avisa con un error por pantalla

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`saltalac_chincol`.`crear_hora`, CONSTRAINT `foreing_rut` FOREIGN KEY (`rut_medico`) REFERENCES `medico` (`rut`))
>
> INSERT INTO `crear_hora` (`rut_medico`, `fecha_programada`, `hora_programada`) VALUES ('11111111-4', '2017/02/14', '19:00')
>
> Filename: models/ChincolModel.php
>
> Line Number: 22

esto me avisa que funciona y esta bien, ahora pregunto ¿como puedo hacer para que en vez de que me lance un error me muestre un numero o un boleano en JSON?

CODE:

```
        public function Insertnewhour(){

        $data = array(
        'rut_medico' => $this->input->post('rut_medico'),
        'fecha_programada' => $this->input->post('fecha_programada'),
        'hora_programada' => $this->input->post('hora_programada')
        );

        $this->load->model('ChincolModel');
        $this->ChincolModel->InsertHora($data);
        
        $rut = $data['rut_medico'];

        if ($rut existe en tabla medicos, cumple con la condicion) {
            
            $satifaction = true;
        }

        else {
            $satifaction = false;
            $thebether = array("registro" => "$satifaction");

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($thebether);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente la acción de insertar hora, con un rut inválido, sea capaz de arrojar una excepción, así que puedes probar capturándola:

```
try {   
    $this->ChincolModel->InsertHora($data);
    $satifaction = true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $satifaction = false;
}

$thebether = array("registro" => "$satifaction");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($thebether);
```

En realidad lo que debieras hacer es verificar el mensaje de la excepción para saber si efectivamente es un error de FK, pero como arreglo rápido, con esto quedas bien encaminado.